# Ajax readyState always = 1 and status =0

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am writing some simple Ajax code which should connect to Java Servlet and return JSON format data.When i put the url in the browser, it shows the JSON format data correctly.But as long as i handled it in the javascript code,the `readyState always ==1` and the status is `always ==0;` I really don't know what happen.

**my code:**

```
var xmlhttp;
function getStock(myform)
{
    companyName = myform.companyName.value;
    if( companyName == "")
    {
        alert("empty");
    }
    else
    {
        url = "http://tomcat.server/examples/servlet/financesearch?symbol="+companyName;
        window.XMLHttpRequest?xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest():xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = processReq;
        console.log(xmlhttp, url);
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);



    }

}
function processReq()
{
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {                   
           // alert("hellp");
            var doc = eval('(' + xmlhttp.responseText + ')');
            alert("gaga"+doc.result[0].Name);
        }
        alert(xmlhttp.readyState +" "+ xmlhttp.status);
}
'''
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you checked the XMLhttpRequests in your browser developer console to see if it received something?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs I added console.log('response=',xmlhttp.responseText); after send() and it shows response=null

Comment: That's normal that it says "response = null", because you're doing async processing. that means that that line is handled after the request is sent, but before it's been returned.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs So how to fix this problem? I am a totally beginner

Comment: Personally, I think Ajax is one of the few times it's actually better to use a 3rd party javascript library like JQuery. It will abstract away all that about open() and send() and readystate and status and whatnot.